# How to schedule the execution of a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql

**I want to run a php script located on my FTP every hour (precisely XX:00).**

My host have a feature called "CRON tasks" to do this. However, I can't pass parameters in the URL (it has to end with .php) and also I found out that the execution was quite approximate (+/- 30 seconds).

I don't have a machine at home running 24h/24h.

This php script only has an SQL request, so I tried to schedule the request directly from mySQL PhpMyAdmin, however I need SUPER rights to do this (and I don't have it).

Is there a solution for this ? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean, url? cron doesn't work with urls. it works with filesystem paths only, and you can pass whatever command-line arguments to the job script you want.

Comment: you need to change the way you catch your params, instead of $_GET use it [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could execute **`curl`** or **`wget`** from cron. You'd supply the URL (with parameters) you want to execute as an argument.

(This assumes that your .php script is available through a web server. I only mention that, because I don't understand what you mean by "located on my FTP".)

As far as the time of execution of a cron task being "approximate (+/-30 seconds)", I've never observed a cron task begin executing *before* the scheduled time.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

If it's only SQL statements that you need to execute, then .php shouldn't be a requirement. You could use the `mysql` command line client. For example, you can throw together a small shell script that calls `mysql`, and then schedule the execution of the shell script with cron.